# Fill array with the alphabet using rand function in C

Tags: c, arrays, random

I'm writing an encode and a decode program, so I need to create an array of the alphabet using rand so it is shuffled. My code below results in duplication of letters. How can I get each of the 26 letters to appear using the rand function? 
I did try creating an array of used characters, but that resulted in characters outside the range 'a' - 'z', mostly spaces.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int key, currch, i;
    char plain[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char coded[26];
    key = atoi(argv[1]);
    srand((unsigned)key);

    for(i=0; i<26; i++) {
            coded[i] = 'a' + rand() % 26;
    }
 // testing to see what is in the array
    i=0; 
    while(i<26) {
            printf("%c ", coded[i]);
            i++;
    }
}
```

The output when using 33 as the seed is

```
z h w p b i h x c q u m a v u v f u k u j j d s y g
```

As you can see, there are duplicates (u, v, j)

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Start by putting the letters into the array once each, in some known order (e.g. the obvious one), and then randomly shuffle the array by repeatedly picking random pairs of elements to swap.  Note that to get an unbiased shuffle, you need to consider each element in turn, and pick another element *at the same position or to its right* to swap it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is wrong, you are getting random values, but not shuffling the array. `plain` isn't used in your code at all.

An efficient shuffling algorithm is [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), also known as Knuth shuffle. The pseudo-code is:

```
for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
   j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
   exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Comment: Plain is a separate array for a different purpose unrelated to my issue. The coded[] is where the shuffled array lives. Both replies help. Thanks!